# Shell script: Copy folder with a new name

Tags: unix, script, shell-script

I'm trying to write this shell script to create in the parent directory a copy of the folders found in the current directory. So far, I wrote this:

```
for folder in *; do

    mkdir ../$folder;
done
```

I'd like to do a "find and replace" operation on the folder name, so that, for instance, folder named `graphics-HD` becomes copied as `graphics-SD`

Sorry if it's simplistic, but I am absolutely not experienced with shell script / unix.

Thanks a lot!
J.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add more details about the find and replace operations you want to cover (unless the answer below covers them all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a trailing slash to the wildcard restricts the output to directories

```
for dir in */; do ...
```

You'll want to read about [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) -- you can do find and replace within the shell:

```
newname=${dir/%-HD/-SD}
```

Comment: What is the percent sign for?

Comment: See the documentation linked in my answer: `If pattern begins with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.`

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with what you have, except it will make folders out of files as well as folders. You can either check that every folder is a directory with [ -d $folder ], or use find. 
From the folder where you have folders that you wish to copy:

```
find -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec mkdir "../{}" \+
```

To search and replace, there is rename from [rename.berlios.de](http://rename.berlios.de). you can rename all folders somewhere like this:

```
renamexm -s/-HD/-SD/ `find . -type d -maxdepth 1`
```